# Abstract models with a parameter in Django

Tags: python, django

Is it possible to create an abstract Django model with a parameter? Like a meta-meta class?

```
class Parent(models.Model):
    field1 = CharField(max_length=100, default=MY_STRING)
    field2 = CharField(max_length=100, default=MY_STRING + ' lorem ipsum')
    field3 = IntegerField(default=5)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class Child(Parent(MY_STRING='abc')):
    # now it should have:
    #   field1 with default value "abc"
    #   field2 with default value "abc lorem ipsum"
    #   field3 with default value 5
```

Comment: Short answer: no.  Unless you start doing some evil mumbo-jumbo thangs with metaclasses, class decorators, monkeypatches etc, that is...

Answer (score 0):

This is a real bad Idea but if you really need to monkeypatch your app... use

def **init**(self, *args):
   """
     My custom code goes here...
   """

Read about custom model fields in the oficial documentation...
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/custom-model-fields/